# setArguments(bundle) is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment, undefined

with a FragmentPagerAdapter I am trying to return a fragment. However I end up in the error setArgument(bundle) is undefined. But I am not suppose to define it, looking at other sample codes

Here is the code

```
    public static SimpleMapActivity newInstance(int position,String title) {
    SimpleMapActivity fragment = new SimpleMapActivity();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", position);
    bundle.putString("title", title);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}
```

The PageAdapter that i created is;

```
        @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            Fragment fragmentByTag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentName(R.id.pager, position));
            System.out.println("*********** fragmentByTag = " + fragmentByTag);
            return SimpleMapActivity.newInstance(position, "Fragment with menu");

        }
```

I could put more code, but i think with this is enough for resolving it, if you want more to see please do not hesitate to ask.
Thanks in advance, 
Alejandro

Comment: SimpleMapActivity does not sound like a Fragment

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleMapActivity` is not extending `Fragment`, that's the reason `setArguments` method is not defined.

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunaly cannot upvote ur answer(i need 15 on reputation)

Comment: Don't worry, but you can accept an answer, so choose the best one. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did SimpleMapActivity exends fragments? it's look like Activity.